# Insert into database select * from database2 where (somecondition) order by xyz

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
INSERT INTO [APL4_WATERPLANT].[dbo].[PRINT_PWD]
    ([DATEANDTIME],[CLT_2101] ,[CT_2101] ,[FT_2101] ,[TT_2101] ,[TT_2102] ,[VT_2101] ,[TOC_2101] ,[GEN_COND] )
   SELECT * 
   FROM 
       [APL4_WATERPLANT].[DBO].[PWD] 
   WHERE 
       [DATEANDTIME] BETWEEN '2013-7-21 0:00:00.000' AND '2013-7-22 0:00:00.000' 
   ORDER BY 
       [DATEANDTIME]
```

Whenever I execute this query, all the values are getting transferred. But they are not in a ordered format ([dateandtime] is a column name which stores data and time). Is something wrong with the query ? Kindly help.

Comment: Do you have any index on this table?

Comment: The target table doesn't have any *implied* order - you only get a guaranteed order if you do a `SELECT` with an `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you insert values into a table, the OREDR of storage cannot be gaurenteed.

If you wish to retrieve the values in an ordered fashion you **HAVE** to use [ORDER BY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

Any order you see by selecting without an `ORDER BY` is purely coincidental.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies. My actual requirement is a reporting application. The first data base only stores data (PWD). Whenever i want to show the data in a specified period (say from 1st to 2nd August). I am executing that query and transferring that particular period data into the second database and displaying it in MS charts application. But in the transferred database as well as MSchart report, i am seeing Jumbled data. How can i avoid this ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: Use ordering in SELECT stements and in the CHARTS.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more ? I am a bit new to this stuff. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: The MSChart should have a sort order that you can set for display purposes. Or the SELECT statement that provides the data for the chart, can also have an order specified. You will have to be more specific regarding the statement that provides the data to the chart, and the settings of the chart.

Comment: I found out how to use sorting in MS Charts. Thank you very much for the support. :D

Comment: How can i use Sorting in Charts in MS Charts Tool ?